# Generate Random code with serial number and character using Angular.js,Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I need one help.I need to generate one random number using Angular.js and PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-show="generatedCode">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Generated Code :</span>
<input type="text" name="discount" id="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Code" ng-model="generated_code" ng-keypress="clearField('code');" ng-readonly="coderead" mg-disabled="codedis">
</div>
<div style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="generateCode();"  id="addProfileData" value="Generate Code" ng-show="gcode" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="changeCode();"  id="addProfileData" value="change" ng-show="change" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-red" ng-click="cancelCode();"  id="addProfileData" value="cancel" ng-show="cancelcode" />
</div>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.gcode=true;
    $scope.generateCode=function(){
        $scope.generatedCode=true;
        $scope.coderead=true;
        $scope.codedis=true;
        $scope.gcode=false;
        $scope.change=true;
        $scope.cancelcode=true;
    }
    $scope.cancelCode=function(){
        $scope.generatedCode=false;
        $scope.gcode=true;
        $scope.change=false;
        $scope.cancelcode=false;
    }
```

Here I need to generate code like `abcd001` the character('i.e-abcd') will remain constant and the serial number will increase to 002,003 and so on at each click.Here if once one code code has generated the next time click it will generate the next serial number code and code should not duplicate.Please help me.

Comment: You need a database on which to store the last code (start at 1). Then on each request fetch the number from the DB, increment, store again and put it into the response. If you don't know how to handle a DB you're far away from a solution and better start studying how to implement a backend. Otherwise, you should know through this simple explanation how to implement everything I said.

Comment: @pid : I know the DB operation.